# Why do I get an error when using cd as env's utility argument?

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables, cd-command

I'm studying the `env` command and trying to understand how it works. Here's the command synopsis:

`env [-iv] [-P altpath] [-S string] [-u name] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]`

I decided to play around with it and tried:

`env cd /home/username`

I get: `env: ‘cd’: No such file or directory`

The result is the same with either `env cd ~` or `env cd`.

So why do I get an error when using cd as env's utility argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `cd` is not a "`utility`", it's a shell "bultin", handled by `env`'s parent shell.

Read `man $SHELL`.

Comment: I figured that might be the problem, but since `env pwd` works fine, I thought it must be something else. But I just found out that when utility is a built-in, the results are actually undefined: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `cd` *is* a utility and *is not* a special built-in utility. A corresponding executable is [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06) and its absence is an issue of POSIX non-conformance of the system, and `env`'s specific handling of special-builtins does not come into play. Indeed, **`env cd` is *specifically required* to work**.

Comment: It's a "utility" in the sense that POSIX uses that word (heck, [the description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) starts by saying "the _cd_ utility shall..."). Just that on some systems it's not available as a _standalone_ program, one with a program file of its own, but only as a builtin utility of the shell. And if `env` is also implemented as a standalone program, it can't access the builtins of the shell. I'm not sure what to say about that last part: "handled by env's parent shell.", since while `env` runs, the parent shell doesn't really do anything.